# 4-bit Full Adder using Two 2-bit Full Adders

Tags: verilog, adder

I have the modules for a 1-bit full adder and 2-bit full adder (built upon the 1-bit adder). May I know how I could go about writing the subsequent 4-bit adder based on the 2-bit adder? This may be a little unorthodox but I'm curious to know as I am new to Verilog.
Thank you!

```
module full_adder(
    input A,
    input B,
    input CIN,
    output S,
    output COUT
    );

    assign S = A ^ B ^ CIN;
    assign COUT = (A & B) | (CIN & (A ^ B));

endmodule

module 2_bit_adder(
    input [1:0] A,
    input [1:0] B,
    input C0,
    output [1:0] S,
    output C2
    );

    wire C1;

    full_adder fu0 (A[0], B[0], C0, S[0], C1);
    full_adder fu1 (A[1], B[1], C1, S[1], C2);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 4 bit adder out of 2 bit adders exactly the same way you make a 2 bit adder out of 1 bit full adders. Concatenate the inputs and outputs and chain the carries.

Answer (score -1):

[[image]

Put the number of inputs equal to all the adder's inputs plus one for the bottommost one. Split them in half. Wire the bottommost one to each bottommost output and input for each adder until you hit the output wall. Wire half the inputs on the adder (minus one for the one just used) on the bottom. Then repeat the process. Wire the 2nd half to the 2nd half of the adders. For outputs, wire the first output to the first output on the wall, then 2nd one to 2nd output, etc. The number of outputs needed is the sum of all the bits from the adders. For example from below, 8 + 4 + 2 = 14B adder

Comment: i couldnt understand the others so i made this

Comment: Btw the simulator is from Digital Logic gates on itch.io

Comment: `number of outputs needed is the sum of all the bits from the adders` Common design flow is requirements specifying interface, and implementation following suit.

Comment: srry but you have to swap the outputs in the full adder to make it easier